# How can I implement a socket reconnection using spring integration TCP?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

While integrating to a TCP endpoint, we created an application using Spring integration TCP where we've a pooled connection using the following beans:

```
<!-- Pooled Connection factory -->
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client" host="${gateway.url}" port="${gateway.port}"
    single-use="true" so-timeout="${gateway.socket.timeout}" serializer="appSerializerDeserializer" deserializer="appSerializerDeserializer" />
<bean id="cachedClient" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="client" />
    <constructor-arg value="${gateway.pool.size}" />
</bean>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to implement a socket re-connection in case a socket loses the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will automatically reconnect the next time you send something.

Comment: Thank you Gary! I saw this behavior but I wasn't sure if that was the preferable way.